Why proper cone can be used to define generalized inequality
I'm currenty studying convex optimization and in Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimization page 43, it mentioned that a cone $K\in\mathbf R^n$ is called a proper cone if it satisfies the following:

$K$ is convex
$K$ is closed
$K$ is solid ,which means it has nonempty interior
$K$ is pointed, which means that it contains no line

The book then goes on to say that a proper cone
$
K$ can be used to define a generalized inequality. However, I am confused about why a proper cone can be used to define a generalized inequality. Later in the book, the concepts of minimum and minimal elements are introduced via dual inequalities. I don't intuitively understand what special properties of proper cones enable them to define generalized inequalities. Why can't non-proper cones be used in this way?

This question is better suited for Math Stackexchange.

Besides the point that the question is a better fit at math stack, it is also not clear enough. Maybe you can be more precise in what you want to know? You define generalized ineq w.r.t. a proper cone K by saying x ≥_K y if x-y is in K. If K is the positive orthant, you get the standard coordinate-wise inequality. You can check how the definition of proper is used to show the axioms of a partial order.
